# Interact with running console application with Python

Tags: python, linux

On my system, I have an already-running console application that receives commands and emits output accordingly. I would like to connect to this application from a python script, and interact with it. Is it possible?

I know I cannot use subprocess or similar because they just launch another process; I need to talk to an already existing one. How can I do it, in detail? Do I need to set up pipes, or sockets? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: How does the other application receive commands?

Comment: What do you mean? I can interact with the application directly by typing into it and I see the output on screen.

Comment: Is this a public application? Is there some kind of documentation?

Comment: "I cannot use subprocess" that's actually the preferred way to do it using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Comment: @Finwood: no, I wrote it. I can adjust it as needed if the input/output can be different.

Comment: If the process is already running then IO redirection isn't the way to go. You need a different kind of IPC, for example connecting to the program with (domain) sockets. However the target application has to support this (for example accepting commands over socket connections). I would write the program this way: Creating a thread that consumes messages/commands from a queue in a loop, another thread reads standard input and feeds commands into the command queue, creating one additional thread per socket connection to read stuff from the sockets and feed commands to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you might want a tool like [reptyr](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) that can re-assign the pty of the process in which you're interested.

You might also investigate the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process) that is similar.

Once you have the pty, then you can either use [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle the interaction.